# System.loadLibrary get stuck and never returns

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk, shared-libraries

Our game stalls as it loads our main library under Android with API level 15 (or 14, haven't test previous versions). **This does not occur on device with API level 16 and above.**

We are using the NDK so our Main.java includes the following lines at its end:

```
static {
    boolean bFMODReady = false;
    try {
      System.loadLibrary("fmod");
      System.loadLibrary("fmodstudio");
      bFMODReady = true;
    } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Unable to load FMOD (" + e.getLocalizedMessage() + ")");
    }

    if (BuildConfig.AMAZON) {
        System.loadLibrary("AmazonGamesJni");
    }

    System.loadLibrary("Main");

    if (!bFMODReady) {
        Log.e(TAG, "FMOD is not ready -> disable audio");
        disableAudio();
    }
}
```

The game stalls at launch with the following log:

```
05-05 00:30:39.017 598-598/com.snip.snap D/dalvikvm: Trying to load lib /mnt/asec/com.snip.snap-1/lib/libMain.so 0x4175c7e8
```

Nothing more. According to previous logs, fmod, fmodstudio and AmazonGamesJni libraries load just fine.

Obviously the loading of libMain.so get stuck for whatever reason. We are compiling our libraries against `c++_static` (with the `APP_STL` value from the `Application.mk` file). We also are using Proguard and multidex.

Here are what we tried to fix the issue but failed:

- compile against either `c++_shared`, `gnustl_static` or `gnustl_shared`;
- deactivate some of the static libraries we are linking our libMain against. Since it's a very lengthy operation we did deactivate just a very few;
- deactivate proguard

What can we do to track down the issue?

Thanks for your help

SO reference:

- [Loading a shared library with the System.loadLibrary call never returns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21915274/loading-a-shared-library-with-the-system-loadlibrary-call-never-returns)
- [android load library failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32860294/android-load-library-failed)

Comment: Have you tried attaching a native debugger, or killing the process with SIGABRT (`kill -6 pid; sleep 1; kill -6 pid`) to get a native stack dump in logcat? It'd be very useful to know where it was stuck.

Comment: Hey fadden, thanks for your answer. We did run the game with the native debugger and we realized the it got stuck because of a OpenGL|ES initialization function. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We figured out that the problem came from a native OpenGL call which was deadlocking.

The takeaway here is to connect your native gdb debugger and break somewhere in your native code to know what's going on.